# Will bootstrap fall-back to html mode if javascript is not supported?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm playing around with the bootstrap css framework and im thinking of using the dropdown menu as well as a couple of pop-up dialogs maybe instead of sending users to a new page saying that their content was submitted, it seems a little more elegant to just show the pop-up javascript message.

However, i know some people have this feature disabled and for those im wondering what the bootstrap css framework will do if a user is trying to submit content for example and then is suppose to get a javascript pop-up message saying "your content was added successfully", does bootstrap has some sort of fall-back for this, by showing an html version or something ? I dont see any information about it on the site..im guessing it doesnt do anything but i was wondering if anyone knew about this..

That being said, facebook is using dropdown menus and dialogs and im guessing they have to use for example javascript for that, so since they have so many users im guessing that javascript isnt such a big problem to be a necessary part of the sites functionality?

Comment: Have you tried turning off javascript and trying it yourself?

Comment: People who turn off JavaScript understand that things are not going to work properly in all kinds of places. That's life, not your problem. That being said, if you have an audience large enough or it is your mandate for that support, you have to do the extra work. Don't expect frameworks you use to do it for you.

Comment: @Diodeus I recommend reading about accessibility. It's not always about other people's problem. Some people just don't have the means to use javascript and then it should be the developer's concern to provide an acceptable user experience.

Comment: I recommend you more carefully read my comment.

Comment: Kevin B: interesting, i will try that on my site, and ill also check out how some of the most popular sites out there is handling this... olaf: so you really think you need to do a lot of extra work for maybe those 2% in the world that doesnt use one of the biggest browsers, how many does actually not use one of these..corporate policy etc is one thing but i dont know if you can expect sites to work if you are using something people rarly use to browsee the web... diodeus: hmm, i guess it depends on the audience

Comment: just tested facebook and no dropdowns or even the chat works, basically you get a box on top that says you should active javascript or go to the very limited mobile site. twitter doesnt seem to use too much of it but the dropdown menu doesnt work at all and they dont give you any information about why..so doesnt seem like two of the most popular sites out there are handling this so well, they basically expect you to have javascript available or enabled

Answer (score 1):

People turn of Javascript knowing things could go wrong, but I would still add this:

```
<noscript>Please enable Javascript in your browser to get the best experience possible when using our website.</noscript>
```